# How do I properly use the layoutId in framer motion to do a image shifts during a page transition in NextJS?

Tags: next.js, framer-motion

What I have right now is a home page that has this structure right here:

```js
<div id="main-container">
      <Header />

      <Hero />

      <ShortDescription />

      <div className={`${styles.selected__work__section} container`}>
        <div className={`section__title`}>
          <h5>\\ Selected work</h5>
          <h5>Discover</h5>
        </div>
        <SelectedWork
          title={`Prasmul Gear Up 2022`}
          description={`Landing page website for an orientation program held by Universitas Prasetiya Mulya`}
          year={2022}
          image={pguImage}
        />

    // ...OTHER COMPONENTS HERE
</div>
```

So basically this `SelectedWork` component is somewhere in the middle of the page. This component looks like this:

```js
const SelectedWork = ({ title, description, year, image }) => {
  return (
    <Link href="/projects">
      <motion.div
        className={styles.works__wrapper}
        initial={{
          opacity: 0,
          y: 100,
        }}
        whileInView={{
          opacity: 1,
          y: 0,
        }}
        transition={{
          duration: 0.5,
        }}
        viewport={{
          once: true,
        }}
      >
        <div className={styles.image__container__wrapper}>
          <motion.div
            className={styles.image__container}
            layoutId={`card-${title}`}
          >
            <div className={styles.image__overlay}>
              <p>See More</p>
            </div>
            <Image
              src={image}
              alt={title}
              sizes="100vw"
              className={styles.image}
            />
          </motion.div>
        </div>
        <div className={styles.work__details}>
          <div>
            <h5 className={styles.title}>{title}</h5>
          </div>
          <div className={styles.description}>
            <h6>{description}</h6>
          </div>
          <h6>{year}</h6>
        </div>
      </motion.div>
    </Link>
  );
};
```

And as a trial, as you can see, if I click on this `SelectedWork` component, it should bring me to a new page called `/projects`. What I'm trying to do is to animate the image to move to the left of the page like in the gif I have attached below. But the issue is that, instead of immediately scaling itself accordingly to the left side of the page, it somehow moves from outside of the page (bottom) to the top and to the left. What I expected was the image to move from where it is originally on screen to the left side of the page instead of from the bottom. What am I missing here? Let me know if you need more information.

Here's a look at `<Projects />`

```js
<div>
      <Header />

      <div className={styles.project__hero}>
        <motion.div
          className={styles.image__container}
          layoutId={`card-Prasmul Gear Up 2022`}
        >
          <Image className={styles.image} src={pguImage} />
        </motion.div>

        <div className={styles.project__hero__content}>
          <h3>Prasmul Gear Up 2022</h3>
          <p>Client: Universitas Prasetiya Mulya</p>
          <p>
            Landing page website for an orientation program held by Universitas
            Prasetiya Mulya
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

[image: Framer Motion Page Transition]